# Crash when installing the app on ipad,  works fine in simulator

Tags: ios, cocoa, ipad, crash

I am gettting the below issue in my application (Pls help me):

```
    *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'CALayerInvalidGeometry', reason: 'CALayer position contains NaN: [1.07157e-08 nan]'
    *** Call stack at first throw:
    (
        0   CoreFoundation                      0x3126a64f __exceptionPreprocess + 114
        1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x32b12c5d objc_exception_throw + 24
        2   CoreFoundation                      0x3126a491 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 68
        3   CoreFoundation                      0x3126a4cb +[NSException raise:format:] + 34
        4   QuartzCore                          0x32c6f61d _ZL18CALayerSetPositionP7CALayerRKN2CA4Vec2IdEEb + 140
        5   QuartzCore                          0x32c6f58b -[CALayer setPosition:] + 38
        6   QuartzCore                          0x32c6f4d7 -[CALayer setFrame:] + 390
        7   UIKit                               0x35a31455 -[UIView(Geometry) setFrame:] + 188
        8   UIKit                               0x35a51743 UIViewCommonInitWithFrame + 594
        9   UIKit                               0x35a514a1 -[UIView initWithFrame:] + 84
        10  CaCaCard                            0x0000683b -[CaCaCardsAppViewController shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:] + 510
        11  UIKit                               0x35a6eead -[UIViewController _isSupportedInterfaceOrientation:] + 48
        12  UIKit                               0x35a6ee6f -[UINavigationController _doesTopViewControllerSupportInterfaceOrientation:] + 46
        13  UIKit                               0x35a6ee37 -[UINavigationController shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:] + 14
        14  UIKit                               0x35a6edbf -[UINavigationController _isSupportedInterfaceOrientation:] + 54
        15  UIKit                               0x35a6fbbb -[UIViewController window:shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:] + 46
        16  UIKit                               0x35a6f857 -[UIWindow _shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:] + 194
        17  UIKit                               0x35a6f4a3 -[UIWindow setAutorotates:forceUpdateInterfaceOrientation:] + 366
        18  UIKit                               0x35a6f0ad -[UIWindow setDelegate:] + 168
        19  UIKit                               0x35a6efa9 -[UIViewController _tryBecomeRootViewControllerInWindow:] + 64
        20  UIKit                               0x35a6d611 -[UIViewController viewDidMoveToWindow:shouldAppearOrDisappear:] + 460
        21  UIKit                               0x35a6d3e5 -[UINavigationController viewDidMoveToWindow:shouldAppearOrDisappear:] + 36
        22  UIKit                               0x35a4c5a7 -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 506
        23  UIKit                               0x35a4c32f -[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:] + 106
        24  UIKit                               0x35a31c1b -[UIView(Internal) _addSubview:positioned:relativeTo:] + 678
        25  UIKit                               0x35a3196b -[UIView(Hierarchy) addSubview:] + 22
        26  CaCaCard                            0x00004bcf -[CaCaCardsAppAppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] + 318
        27  UIKit                               0x35a61821 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForURL:payload:suspended:] + 772
        28  UIKit                               0x35a5bb65 -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 272
        29  UIKit                               0x35a307d7 -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 1114
        30  UIKit                               0x35a30215 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 44
        31  UIKit                               0x35a2fc53 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 5090
        32  GraphicsServices                    0x31d37e77 PurpleEventCallback + 666
        33  CoreFoundation                      0x31241a97 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 26
        34  CoreFoundation                      0x3124383f __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 166
        35  CoreFoundation                      0x3124460d __CFRunLoopRun + 520
        36  CoreFoundation                      0x311d4ec3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 230
        37  CoreFoundation                      0x311d4dcb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 58
        38  UIKit                               0x35a5ad49 -[UIApplication _run] + 372
        39  UIKit                               0x35a58807 UIApplicationMain + 670
        40  CaCaCard                            0x000028e7 main + 70
        41  CaCaCard                            0x0000289c start + 40
    )
    terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'
    Program received signal:  “SIGABRT”.
    warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.3.5 (8L1)/Symbols/Developer/usr/lib/libXcod

eDebuggerSupport.dylib (file not found).
(gdb) 

-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
//-----------------------------------
{   
    if ( self.interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait ||
        self.interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown  )
    {
        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.5];

        [UIView beginAnimations:@"View Flip" context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.25];
        [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:
         UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight];

        UIScreen *screen = [UIScreen mainScreen];
        CGFloat screenWidth = screen.bounds.size.width;
        CGFloat screenHeight = screen.bounds.size.height;
        UIView *navView = [[self navigationController] view];
        navView.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, screenHeight, screenWidth);
        navView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
        navView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degreesToRadian(90));
        navView.center = CGPointMake(screenWidth/2.0, screenHeight/2.0);

        [UIView commitAnimations];

    }

    fontSelected = NO;

}
```

Comment: whether your code performing any animation while rotation?

Comment: @rishi: please see my updated code which has the animation code

Comment: It says the crash is related to initializing a new view inside your CaCaCardsAppViewController's shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: method (maybe a bad frame size?).  What does that code look like?

Comment: @user198725878 - seems like issue related to setting of frame in animation. You can go with Dancreek solution and check if that works?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is an invalid frame size you are setting at some point. Probably a rect with a zero value somewhere.

From your code I would suspect you are getting some unexpected values back when you are asking for the screen size.

Also don't use those old animation functions. Use the block based animation. It's much better.